# Run SQL from VBA button

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

What do I need to add/modify to this code to have txtDisease1 be populated with the results of strSQL? As of now the textbox populates with the SQL query. I'm sure it is a simple fix but for the life of me I can not find the answer.

```
Private Sub btnDNA_Click()
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT LastName From Patient WHERE PatientID = 1"
Me.txtDisease1.Value = strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `strSql` is literally only the text "SELECT LastName From Patient WHERE PatientID = 1" and not the executed result of the query it describes. Using the `DLOOKUP` function as @Emi has suggested is the simpler approach for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I know DLookup but I need to use SQL because the queries will get more complex. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oh ok, see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DLookup` function.

```
Me.txtDisease1.Value = DLookup("LastName", "Patient", "PatientID = 1")
```

Comment: I know DLookup but I need to use SQL because the queries will get more complex. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've not been able to test this, but I think this should work.

```vb
Private Sub btnDNA_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    strSQL = "SELECT LastName From Patient WHERE PatientID = 1"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    Me.txtDisease1 = rs!LastName

    rs.close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complex lookups or to hit other data sources, you can use ADO (requires reference to Microsoft Active X Data Objects)

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "SELECT TOP 1 LastName From Patient WHERE PatientID=1", _
    CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.txtDisease1.Value = rs(0)
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```